# different items in listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to create a listview with different items within it. I want to use a switch statement to do this but I'm struggling to produce this I have created this with one XML layout how can I use multiple XML Layouts.  I've attached my code - thank you in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_postlist);

        this.generateDummyData();

        ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.postListView);
        final PostItemAdapter itemAdapter = new PostItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.generateDummyData());


        listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    }

    private ArrayList<PostData> generateDummyData() {
        PostData data = null;
        ArrayList<PostData> listData = new ArrayList<PostData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            data = new PostData();
            data.postTitle = "Person " + (i + 1)
                    + " Name Surname";
            data.postThumbUrl = null;
            listData.add(data);
        }

        return listData;
    }

    // Get dummy data for Activity Feed

    class PostDataTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

        ArrayList<PostData> recentTracks;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... page) {
            try {
                // Get a page of 15 tracks
                // Simplified - getPage accepts 'page' and 'limit' parameters and returns a Collection<Track>
                recentTracks = new ArrayList<PostData>();

                Thread.sleep(3000);

                PostData data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    data = new PostData();
                    data.postTitle = "Person " + (i + 1)
                            + " Name  is the Post Title from RSS Feed";
                    data.postThumbUrl = null;
                    recentTracks.add(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postListView);
            PostItemAdapter adapter = ((PostItemAdapter) ((HeaderViewListAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).getWrappedAdapter());

            if (adapter == null) {
                adapter = new PostItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), recentTracks);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                adapter.addAll(recentTracks);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }


    }


    public class PostItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostData> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<PostData> items;
        private int currentPage = 0;

        public PostItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PostData> recentTrackArrayList) {
            super(context, 0, recentTrackArrayList);
            this.context = context;
            this.items = recentTrackArrayList;
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.postitem,
                        parent, false);
            }

            final PostData item = items.get(position);

            rowView = convertView;
            ImageView thumbImageView = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.postThumb);
            if (items.get(position).postThumbUrl == null) {
                thumbImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.postthumb_loading);
            }

            TextView postTitleView = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.postTitleLabel);
            postTitleView.setText(items.get(position).postTitle);

            if (position == getCount() - 1) {
                currentPage++;
                new PostDataTask().execute(currentPage);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: see [Android Listview with multiple row layout](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html) tutorial probably help

Comment: If you use PostData object for both layouts, then before you inflate layout you can check your object data and based on that pick layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At **first** use [ViewHolder](http://optimizationtricks.blogspot.com/2014/01/tricks-to-boost-performance-of-list-view.html) pattern.

At **second** make `interfase` of `Item` which will include two methods:

- `getType()` - which return the type of your item;
- `getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView)` - which return the view of row. Inside this method create `ViewHolder` instance, then inflate `View` parameter to `VH` and do some action with result view.

. Then create 2 (or how much u need) classes which would implement `Item`. Define methods. Then in `ListAdapter` in `getView()` call `getView()` of items and return it to list.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `view holder` pattern won't work if your items are completely different.

For every item, you need to check what kind of item you want to display and inflate a different view depending on it (for example, using a `switch` as you said)

Comment: Could I adjust my code to do this? (Sorry I'm new to android and thought I hadn't used the view holder)